# Using Linux environmental variables as a path in Perl script

Tags: linux, perl, environment-variables

I am trying to use an environmental variable to point to a file, run it through a subroutine and associate it with a variable. I managed it with Windows but I cannot get the syntax working for Linux..

This is what I have:

```
 my $config = read_config("$ENV{APP_HOME}/config/APP-linux.cfg");
```

my script dies when reaching this line with the error:

```
    Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"APP_HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at ./XXXXX.pl
```

APP_HOME is defined as an environment variable (confirmed using set). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does `echo $APP_HOME` returns the correct value from your shell?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it doesnt... it gives:
    Name "main::APP_HOME" used only once: possible typo at ./test.pl line 8.
Can't call method "echo" on an undefined value at ./test.pl line 8.

Comment: In your terminal, not from inside of Perl.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, whoops sorry. It gives the expected directory path

Comment: Did you just set it or export it?   export APP_HOME=MY_VALUE

Comment: What does this display: `perl -e 'print "$ENV{APP_HOME}\n";'`

Comment: Examine your full list of environment variables: `perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper \%ENV'`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it does not print anything...

Comment: @Miller my environment variable is not showing in the list.. What have I done wrong? Added some more detail in the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was of my own stupidity. I set the variable in .bashrc using:

```
APP_HOME=$HOME/APP/DATA/STORAGE; export FINE_DIR
```

The RAPID_DIR had no right to be there. Was a remainder of a copy/paste and poor oversight... Changes FINE_DIR to APP_HOME and all is good.

Thankyou for all the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

In bash, `=` simply creates a shell variable. These are not automatically exported to the environment. You need to do that explicitly.

Set a shell variable:

```
 $ AA=hello
```

Set and export another one (in a single statement):

```
 $ export BB=there
```

Start a new process:

```
 $ bash
```

Voila! Only the exported variable is inherited by the new process:

```
 $ echo "[$AA] [$BB]"
 [] [there]
```

**Note** that `set` does *not* set a variable. `set AA=hello` does not do what the Windows shell does.